How to refactor/rename package directory on every submodule?
I want to refactor packages in my project modules but I don't want to refactor each package one by one because the project has many modules. How can I do this quickly and easily?
Answer 1 (from other post)
Use InteliJ IDE refactoring menu.
For example, If I need to change google.project.json.gson and google.project.json.gson.reader to com.google.gson and com.google.gson.reader, refactor/rename package menu is not helpful.
It supports only 
com.google.gson."hi"
to
com.google.gson."hello"
not
com.google."gson.hi"
to
com.google."higson"

Answer 2 (from other post)
Use directory tool, You can change directory.
Sorry, Its java project.
It has package path.
Can I get some good idea?
If you need more information, please comment. thanks. :)
